# I+I are isomorphic I

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let I=R\Q.  Need to prove that I+I is isomorphic to I. 
Really have no ideas how to do it. I know what is isomorphism means, but don't understand how to build the isomorphism here. Hope someone will put me on a right way.
UPD: + means here that we have set which consist of the set of irrational numbers and its copy. And there is order on this set: x

Comment: What is $+$, in this context?

Comment: @amrsa I wondered the same thing. Then I noticed he said $\setminus$, not $/$. So $I\subset\mathbb R$;  hence the standard definition would be $I+I=\{i+j:i,j\in I\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphism? A bijection?

Comment: + means here that we have set which consist of the set of irrational numbers and its copy. And there is order on this set: x<y if: 1) x is from I, y is from copy 2) x,y are from I and x<y 3) x,y are from copy and x<y. By isomorphism I mean a bijection that saves the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote the two copies of $I$ by $I_1$ and $I_2$.
If I didn't misunderstand you, you want an order-isomorphism $f: I \to I_1 + I_2$ (using your notation).
Consider the function
$$x \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
x + 2 &\text{ if } x \leq -1\\
-1/x  &\text{ if } -1 \leq x < 0\\
-1/x  &\text{ if } 0 < x \leq 1\\
x - 2 &\text{ if } 1 \leq x,
\end{cases}
$$
where we consider $I_1$ as a copy of $I \cap (-\infty,0)$, under the first two branches of the function, and $I_2$ as a copy of $I \cap (0,+\infty)$, under the last two.
It is easy to show that the first two branches define an order-isomorphism from $I \cap (-\infty,0)$ to $I$ and the last two, from $I \cap (0,+\infty)$ to $I$ too.

So what this function really does is to map isomorphically (with respect to the order) both the negative and the positive irrationals to the whole set of irrationals.